# How do I read correctly from a firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to read the "total_event_created" value of the following data.

[image]

This is part of my code.

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return database.ref('users/' + user_id).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
          var total_event_counter = snapshot.val().total_event_created;
          console.log("total_event_counter",total_event_created);
        });
    });
```

I want the value to then use it for reference.

```
database.ref('events/' + user_id + total_event_created).set({ stuff here });
```

The problem is that I am getting this message in the console.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something along the lines of:

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return database.ref('users/' + user_id).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  return total_event_counter = snapshot.val().total_event_created;
    }).then(function(tec) {
      console.log(tec);
    });
});
```

Comment: Got this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'total_event_created' of null

Comment: And you didn't get that before? I haven't changed that part of your code.

Comment: Got it. I saw what was my mistake. I was using as reference the user id, but in the data I had a random number as the key of the users. I fixed it.

Comment: Just a question. What the return means in this case?

Comment: your first return was returning the promise, so in there we are now returning an actual value which you can process.